# Entered data in access table not showing in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C# and I have a win Form with a ComboBox Customer_CmbBx which gets its value list from an access table called CustomerTable. With another form I can add to the Table which works. But when I come to look at the values in the combobox they havn't changed. Even if I shut down the Database and re open it. The new Value isn't listed. The Code for the combobox is below

```
private void LoadCustomerOnCombo()
{
    string strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.Database2ConnectionString;
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
    {
        try
        {
            string strSql = "Select * from CustomerTable";
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(strSql, conn));
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            Customer_cmbBx.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            Customer_cmbBx.ValueMember = "Customer";
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems as if any change to the Table isn't being listed. As even manually changing a record shown in the Table isn't being shown by the combobox. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Probably the `ComboBox` shows the old values and it is not refreshed after changes. So I guess you need to refresh the `ComboBox` to apply changes.

Comment: Adding a refresh on the combobox had no effect. looking at the dataset that the combobox gets its values from hasn't changed. The dataset is supposed to read the table and the combobox reads its item list from the dataset. But it appears that the dataset only read the Table once and all future records in the table are being ignored/not seen.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was because I was using the default connection string Properties.Settings.Default.Database2ConnectionString;
instead of using my own. Changed it now and everything works fine.